# Symfony and Assetic; NodeJS' UglifyCSS gives a syntax error

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, assetic

I have a Symfony/Assetic installation on Windows 10, along with Node.js with uglifycss 0.0.27. I got the version number from the command line without issue.

The following is my config in Symfony for Assetic;

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: false
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        uglifycss:
            bin: C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifycss
```

And the following is the filter set in my Twig template for my CSS files;

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/app/css/*' filter='cssrewrite, uglifycss' output='css/compiled/main.css' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

When I run php bin/console assetic:dump, I get the following error

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]
  An error occurred while running:
  "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.EXE" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifycss" "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
  \ass6151.tmp"
  Error Output:
  C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\uglifycss:2
  basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
            ^^^^^^^
  SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
      at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
      at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
      at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
      at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
  Input:
  .blue{
      background-color: orange;
  }
```

For reference, here is that the folder set in the Assetic folder contains;

[image: Node Files]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the uglifycss file should point to node_modules\uglifycss\uglifycss. But this doesn't seem to work on Windows for some reason. So I went and pointed directly to that in the config, and now it seems to work proper.

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/node_modules/uglifycss/uglifycss" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```